# How can I run my browser only one time

Tags: c#, loops, selenium, webdriver, instance

I want to start my browser only one time and then get unstatic information from there. But my browser starts many times. How can I start it only one time and close it, when my bool = false;

```
class Program
    {
        public static bool GameIsRun = true;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CheckGame();
        }

        public static ChromeDriver GetDriver()
        {
            return new ChromeDriver();
        }

        public static void CheckGame()
        {
            while (GameIsRun)
            {
                GetInformation(GetDriver());
            }
        }

        static void GetInformation(ChromeDriver driver)
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("myURL");
            do
            {
               //loop for doing something on this page, I don't want to start my browser many times.  
            }
            while ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you ever hear something About "if else" ?

Comment: yes, sure. How can it help me to start the browser one time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this will work for you.

```
class Program
    {
        public static bool GameIsRun = true;
        public static IWebDriver driver = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CheckGame();
        }

        public static ChromeDriver GetDriver()
        {
            if(driver == null){
                 driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            return driver;
        }

        public static void CheckGame()
        {
            while (GameIsRun)
            {
                GetInformation(GetDriver());
            }
        }

        static void GetInformation(ChromeDriver driver)
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("myURL");
            do
            {
               //loop for doing something on this page, I don't want to start my browser many times.  
            }
            while ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your time on me. I need some time to check it.

Comment: @Murthi : Have you tried your own answer ? The code you have provided has flows. The thing is it won't open the new windows every time but it would reload the same URL every time because of while(GameIsRun) loop.

Comment: Yep, I fixed it. Thanks a lot for your time for me !

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0103 The name 'driver' does not exist in the current context testo C:\Users\The Vee\source\repos\testo\testo\Program.cs 31 Active

Comment: Fixed! Thanks , I am sorry!

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind this is `while (GameIsRun)` code . **GameIsRun** is always true that is why it goes to infinite loop.

How you can overcome this **issue** :  you have to make the value of **GameIsRun** false after launching the browser just like this :

```
public static void CheckGame()
            {
                while (GameIsRun)
                {
                    GetInformation(GetDriver());
                    GameIsRun = false;
                }
            }
```

Use this code , once the browser has launched , it would make `GameIsRun` as false.

Hope it'll help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: @TheVee : Murthi solution is not right in my opinion , I tried his code . Did his code work for you ?

Comment: @TheVee : What happens in his code , that same URL is being reloaded every time. beacaus of while(GameIsRun) is always true. Please verify this behavior.

Comment: I use this option and my browser starts only one time.

Comment: @TheVee : I use this option means my answer ? If so you should accept this answer not other’s. Note that future redaer would prefer answers with acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can use singleton concept.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
  private static Singleton instance=null;

  private Singleton()
  {
  }

  public static Singleton Instance
  {
    get
    {
        if (instance==null)
        {
            instance = new Singleton();
        }
        return instance;
    }
   }
 }
```

Hope this will help you.